# Apache htaccess -> Nginx rewrites

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

Help me please to write nginx rewrites instead of that Apache htaccess:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ $1$2/ [R,L]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_RDR} ^$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.site\.com$
  #RewriteCond %2 !www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&()\-+";=\\/|]*)$ blogs/fake/%2/$1 [L,E=RDR:1]


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/urlrewriteprepend.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /urlrewriteprepend.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the [nginx HttpRewriteModule documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule) - everything you need to know should be available in this document.